# Which web development framework is the right one for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, codeigniter, web-frameworks

I'm a college student trying to make a web community with friends. Although we are not experienced developers by any means, we have taken courses on JAVA and some web programming languages (PHP, JAVASCRIPT, CSS, HTML).

At this point, we need to decide on a web framework and begin learning. I have narrowed down my list to Ruby on Rails and Codeigniter, but I am really not sure why I should pick one over the other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no time constraint (as you need to learn both ruby lang and rails framework) and want to know the best practices, i would recommend RubyonRails.

If you have time constraint, then go ahead with Codeigniter. It is easy to learn and well documented.

Answer (score 3):

Pick the one you want to learn and go with it.

I will personally recommend Rails because:

- it teaches you a lot of best practices if you do things the Rails Way™
- Ruby is a fun, easy-to-learn, expressive language
- the community is really big, enthusiastic, and very helpful
- there's great books and tutorials available all over the internet

Comment: I like rails a lot but LOVE ruby. And rails is open source, meaning no one gets paid to work on it - instead people work on it because they are passionate about it. This REALLY shows when you start using it. It's also built pragmatically - there's no ivory tower theorizing going on. Most of the stuff that gets added to rails is because it solves real world problems. Yes, I'm pretty biased but I worked on the MS web dev stack for over 10 years. 6 months with rails/ruby was enough to make me switch.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like *the good framework*. It highly depends on, in no particular order :

- your skills
- your tastes (Yes, it does matter a lot)
- your willingness to learn
- technical constraints. Your hosting company may support only Ruby or only PHP
- ...

I personally had the occasion to develop with CodeIgniter and I pretty much enjoyed it. It is light, well documented and leaves you with a lot of freedom.
I also have a good friend for whom Ruby On Rails is the only framework deserving the name of "framework".

If your project is ambitious, a good idea to make your point could be to make a trivial application like a TODO list with both framework and then pick the one that fits your need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply